Interleaved Execution not happening in SQL 2017 DB
We have a SQL Server 2017 database that was imported from a 2008 instance long ago. The compatibility level is set to 140 (confirmed by the execution plans), but no multi-statement TVFs are ever executed with interleaving and always have cardinality estimates of 100.
I ran these test queries against the WideWorldImportersDW DB and they were executed with Interleaving, but when I create the relevant objects in my original DB and run the queries there, no interleaved execution occurs (see both plans below).
I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this and what, if anything, can be done to fix it. Thanks in advance.

The sys.database_scoped_configurations DMV does NOT contain DISABLE_INTERLEAVED_EXECUTION_TVF.  I do NOT get interleaved execution if I add a DISABLE_BATCH_MODE_ADAPTIVE_JOINS hint.  Parameterization is set to Simple in both databases.
The Interleaved_exec_disabled_reason extended event is firing with reason Parameter Sniffing. sys.database_scoped_configurations has Parameter Sniffing = 0 in the old database, but 1 in the new.
Changed the old database to Parameter Sniffing = 1, and Interleaved Execution is now working.

Bad plan
Good Plan




Interleaved execution cannot work with parameter sniffing disabled. The current implementation needs the sniffed values for the initial compilation and partial execution to capture runtime TVF cardinality.
It is a shame the documentation does not mention this, or many of the other reasons that can be reported by the Interleaved_exec_disabled_reason extended event. Extended events documentation is also rather thin, in general.
